# Why is ActiveRelation returning an array when I call merge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models called `User`, `Activity`, and `Task` and I can do the following

```
> puts Activity.joins(:task).to_sql
SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "activities"."task_id" ORDER BY date DESC

> puts User.first.shared_tasks.to_sql
SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "user_tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "user_tasks"."task_id" WHERE "user_tasks"."user_id" = 1
```

But when I try to `merge` the two, I get an array:

```
> puts Activity.joins(:task).merge(User.first.shared_tasks).to_sql
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sql' for []:Array
```

Why is that not returning a relation? I need to put a where clause on it.

Update:

Upon further inspection, it looks likes `User.first.shared_tasks` is being evaluated to an array of tasks immediately. I can gett the behavior I want by adding an `order` call:

```
> puts Activity.joins(:task).merge(User.first.shared_tasks.order()).to_sql
SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "activities"."task_id" INNER JOIN "user_tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "user_tasks"."task_id" WHERE "user_tasks"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Is there a better way to prevent that relation from being evaluated besides adding an empty `order`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I still have not figured out why `User.first.shared_tasks` is being immediately evaluated, but I have figured out a work around. I can just call `scoped`:

```
> User.first.shared_tasks.class
=> Array

> User.first.shared_tasks.scoped.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Now when I try to do the merge:

```
Activity.joins(:task).merge(User.first.shared_tasks.scoped)
```

It uses `ActiveRecord::Relation#merge` instead of `Array#merge`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you call a method on a relation object that it doesn't respond to, it delegates that method to some other type of object. In the case of `merge`, it will be converted to an array. This is done via the [ActiveRecord::Delegation module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb). Some methods such as `each` are [explicitly delegated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L6), and others such as `merge` are done through [method_missing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L35).

For example, if you do:

```
Activity.joins(:task).each { |activity| puts activity }
```

the relation delegates `.each` to an array (Enumerator), essentially doing a conversion.

Comment: But merge is a method on Relation

Comment: I don't think the relation merge is doing what you think it is. It seems like it's used for merging additional find options, such as limit, offset, etc. When you use it the way you are, it's returning an array https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d22592a05b299c21e30ec8b38890a178dca863b4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb#L7

Comment: Activity.joins(:task).merge(Activity.limit(10)).to_sql is an example of how you would use it and retain the relation object.

Comment: I see. What I actually wanted to do was another join.

Answer (score 0):

For relation you can try this

```
puts (Activity.joins(:task) & User.first.shared_tasks).to_sql
```

merge helps in create a scope and it returns an array of resulted objects.